# Uploading a new version of a Python file to Azure Databricks requires cluster restart

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am playing with Azure Databricks. I uploaded a Python file and added it to the spark context with

```
spark.sparkContext.addPyFile('/location/to/the/file/model.py')
```

Everything works fine when I run my Python code in the notebook. But when I make a change to the `model.py` file and uploaded it with `--overwrite`, the code in the notebook does not pick up the new version of the file, instead still uses the old one until I restart the cluster.

Is there a way to avoid cluster restart whenever I overwrite a file?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it doesn't work this way - when file is added, it's distributed to all workers and used there.

But you may do it differently - you can use feature of the Repos called [arbitrary files](https://docs.databricks.com/repos.html#enable-support-for-arbitrary-files-in-databricks-repos) (don't forget restart cluster after enabling it), so when you clone your repository into Repos, then you can use Python files (**not notebooks**) from that repository as [Python packages](https://docs.databricks.com/repos.html#work-with-python-and-r-modules).  And then in the notebook, you can use following directives to force reload of changes into notebook environment:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

You can see an example of such usage in [this demo](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-nutter-projects-demo) - Python code from `my_package` directory is used in [the notebook](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-nutter-repos-demo/blob/master/unit-tests/test_with_arbitrary_files.py#L11).